# How to display one of two options for parameter in view file laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-routing, laravel-views

I created a view file with the syntax :
`my name: {{$name}} and mail {{$email}}`
and I need to create a route with 2 parameters (one optional and one required) and this will be the sentence that will be shown : my name : ["name" or "name missing"] and mail ["email"] but I can't display the second option (when the name paramter isn't included), that's my route ;

```php
 Route::get('/users/{name?}/{email}', function($name = NULL, $email){
    if(isset($name)){
        return view('users', compact('name','email'));
    }
    else {
        return view('users', compact(missing name,'email'));
    }
});
```

I know that my problem is in the `else` but I don't know what to write inside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your view file you have to check `name` null or value.

```
Route::get('/users/{email}/{name?}', function($email, $name = NULL){

    return view('users', compact('name','email')); 
});
```

And your view check

```
@if(isset($name))
    //do something
@else
    // Do something
@endif
```

Comment: @AANoman  ok, I can't check the ```name``` null or value in my route?

Comment: @AANoman It was helpful but still dosn't work and It display the Error 404, that's my view :
 ```laravel                 @if(isset($name))
                    my name : {{$name}} and mail {{$email}}
                @else
                    my name : name missing and mail {{$email}}
                @endif ```

Comment: when `$name=null` then `dd($name, $email)` This may help you most. Or in your view  first check `{{dd($name, $mail)}}` then you decision what you want

Comment: @AANoman you are helpul but still error.. don't know what to do

Comment: @@AANoman No, if I write ```http://localhost/recruit/public/users/hjksdhgk@gmail.com``` It dosn't work (404 Error), maybe it's because ```name``` is before ```mail``` and I can't leave it empty?

Comment: I ask you before when `$name=null` then `dd($name, $email)`. If not solve you have to order your route mail then name then try. May be it will solve your problem.

Comment: @AANoman OK, that works, now my Route is : ```laravel Route::get('/users/{email}/{name?}', function($email, $name = NULL){ 
        return view('users', compact('email','name'));
}); ```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213086/discussion-between-a-a-noman-and-yshai-siboni).